# Meteor Js - Creating Project Error encountered "RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded"

Tags: meteor

im new to meteor js, i need help on how to fix this problem i encountered when creating a new project, even calling "meteor" on the command line. Though I was able to create 1 successful project at first try but after that, i cannot be able to duplicate the process anymore.

i hope you experts can assist me on my issue. Thank you in advance and more power to stackoverflow and meteor js.

kindly see the link below to see the command line screenshot. thanks

["RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T5AuY.png)

Update:
 - i already removed the installation folder ".meteor" and re install meteor but apparently i still encounter the same issue. pls help

Comment: What's q.js? Is it some node module you installed by youself?

Comment: hi blueren, thanks for the msg. i am not sure about q.js but i guess its part of the meteor installer package, since i recently deleted this folder "C:\Users\Jayson\AppData\Local\.meteor\" and reinstalled a new copy of meteor api, its already there.

Comment: I have the exact same issue, after a recent Meteor update, so also need help on this. Did you ever find a resolution JaySon?
TY,
Ian.